# How to open multiple simultaneous connection with Xdebug in PHP

Tags: php, nginx, xdebug

We have one central PHP 7.2 server with nginx and php-fpm on one machine. I followed the instructions of PhpStorm multiple Xdebug (debug proxy) connections guide and also `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1`. Both of them works fine for multiple developers but when one developer starts a debug session and suspend on a breakpoint, whole server hangs and waits that for release. At that point server doesn't respond any request with or without Xdebug.

Is Xdebug support simultaneous debug sessions? If it is, how can I do it work properly? May be the problem on the php-fpm side. Is php-fpm can handle multiple requests at the same time (concurrency or parallelism)?

Comment: It must be your php-fpm then. Xdebug runs as part of PHP process (as any other extension) -- it's not shared between them ... so as long as 2nd request will be served by another process/handler/whatever .. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Xdebug uses one debugging connection per script. It does not matter for Xdebug whether multiple scripts create multiple debugging connections at the same time.

PhpStorm has a setting that configures how many simultaneous debugging connections it can handle. The default is in some cases 1, which may cause the problem that you're seeing.

You can configure this number in File->Settings->Languages&Frameworks->PHP->Debug->External Connections->Max. simultaneous connections. Set this value to something like 5 or 10.